# Knowing of a drugged meth head mentally unstable mother - what help is out there for the children?

Tags: pre-schooler, parents, development, drugs, addiction

Even with the assistance of the state controlled agencies the results have been very lacking.
2 are under the age of 8 and the other is 16. The mother is now smoking cannabis with the daughter as well as the father who is only there to provide drugs to the mum. Its a fairly sad and definitely terrible situation to have been witness to a few times.

Comment: Maybe weird question, but from the Netherlands? because i know the exact same issue here... but nothing can be done about it due to the mothers parents being technically the legal guardians...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is not a whole lot you can do.  Not without doing more harm than good.  A parent that uses, does not automatically make them a unacceptable parent, and a neglectful parent is still better than no parent.  As long as the child is not in clear and present danger, directly associated with the parents, social workers would prefer the child stay with them.  It's a rarity that a child improves their situation going into a foster home.  The best thing you can do is be quietly mindful of the situation.  My oldest went to school while we still lived in the city.  All of her friends parents were drug addicts, and many of her friends were on hard drugs by 13. That is not an exaggeration.  even now in the suburbs with my youngest we still see it a bit.  My son's best friend's parents are junkies.  We try to listen for signs of serious issues, which thankfully, there hasn't been any that we know of.  We offer to watch him, feed him and allow him to stay at the house, as long as his parents don't mind.  Do not oppose their parents wishes.  This makes you look worse than them.  You need to have a legitimate safety concern before escalating the issue, not just prejudices on parenting tactics.  For the most part, be a good person and that should cover it.